# error: lipo: not files specified when trying to run the project

Tags: swift, frameworks, lipo

im getting this error when I compile the project. This only happens to me. My other co-workers doesn't have this issue.

```
error: lipo: no input files specified
usage: lipo <input_file> <command> [<options> ...]
  command is one of:
    -archs
    -create
    -detailed_info
    -extract <arch_type> [-extract <arch_type> ...]
    -extract_family <arch_type> [-extract_family <arch_type> ...]
    -info
    -remove <arch_type> [-remove <arch_type> ...]
    -replace <arch_type> <file_name> [-replace <arch_type> <file_name> ...]
    -thin <arch_type>
    -verify_arch <arch_type> ...
  options are one or more of:
    -arch <arch_type> <input_file>
    -hideARM64
    -output <output_file>
    -segalign <arch_type> <alignment>
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
mv: rename /Users/42427/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME/Build/Products/Debug (UAT)-iphonesimulator/GBM.app/Frameworks/PatronSDK.framework/PatronSDK-merged to /Users/42427/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME/Build/Products/Debug (UAT)-iphonesimulator/GBM.app/Frameworks/PatronSDK.framework/PatronSDK: No such file or directory
```

The PatronSDK is a framework embed with the project, is not a Pod. I tried to search the specified directory and I realice that one file is missing and its the PatronSDK. That file is automatically created in the project of my co-workers however in my project is missing after the compilation is finished.

I tried to add the file manually into the directory. Do a clean build but have the same result. After compile, the file is missing in the directory.

I also tried to delete the derived data, delete Xcode and installing again, clone again the project in other route but the issue is always the same

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I'm running out of options